# Change Application Developer Name iOS App Store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have distribute my application on itunes.Application is ready for sale.now i want to change the name of developer. for example app name is "IOS APP" and under the name of Application .[Image for detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFmdV.png)

Comment: You need to register a new developer account with Apple as a different legal entity and transfer the app to that entity

Comment: any other method ...

Comment: can i change this when uploading the next version of the application

Comment: No, you can only change the name if you transfer the app to a different legal entity or if there is a mistake in the name that is currently shown and the current name does not match your legal name (in the case of an individual) or your corporation name (in the case of an company membership)

Comment: i wrote this name by mistake .
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/find-course/id1086319449?ls=1&mt=8
when you see this application seller name is different .i want to add the seller name under the application name.

Comment: There is information in the linked duplicate on contacting Apple to resolve errors in your developer name